# Circle Plot with Color Bar

Tags: python, dataframe, geometry, colorbar, scatter

I'm trying to do a Circle Plot with a Color Bar, almost like this:

[image]

However, the minimum value of the colour bar is currently 1; I would like to be able to set it to 0.

```
import pandas            as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,4], 
                   'B':[3,1,5,1,2,4,5,2,3], 
                   'C':[4,2,4,1,3,3,4,2,1]})

# set the Colour
x              = df.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled       = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df_S           = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
c1             = df['C']
c2             = df_S[2]
colors         = [cm.jet(color) for color in c2]

# Graph
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
for a, b, color in zip(df['A'], df['B'], colors):
    circle = plt.Circle((a, 
                         b), 
                         1, # Size
                         color=color, 
                         lw=5, 
                         fill=False)
    ax.add_artist(circle)

plt.xlim([0,5])
plt.ylim([0,5])
plt.xlabel('A')
plt.ylabel('B')
ax.set_aspect(1.0)

sc = plt.scatter(df['A'], 
                 df['B'], 
                 s=0, 
                 c=c1, 
                 cmap='jet', 
                 facecolors='none')
plt.grid()

cbar = plt.colorbar(sc)
cbar.set_label('C', rotation=270, labelpad=10)

plt.show()
```

Credit to this original question:
[Plotting circles with no fill, colour & size depending on variables using scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563373/plotting-circles-with-no-fill-colour-size-depending-on-variables-using-scatte/50992630#50992630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to alec_djinn this answer does:

- Set the min & max values of the colour bar
- Control the colour of the circles (variable C) on the same range as the colour bar

[image]

```
import pandas            as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
from sklearn import preprocessing
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,4], 
                   'B':[3,2,5,1,2,4,5,2,3], 
                   'C':[4,2,4,1,3,3,4,2,1]})

# set the Colour
x              = df[['C']].values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled       = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df_S           = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
c1             = df['C']
c2             = df_S[0]
cmap           = cm.jet # Use the same Cmap

# Set the Colour Scale
vmin = 0
vmax = 5
norm = Normalize(vmin, vmax)

# Graph
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
for a, b, c in zip(df['A'], df['B'], df['C']):
    circle = plt.Circle((a, 
                         b), 
                         1, # Size
                         color=cmap(norm(c)), 
                         lw=5, 
                         fill=False)
    ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.xlim([0,5])
plt.ylim([0,5])
plt.xlabel('A')
plt.ylabel('B')
ax.set_aspect(1.0)
sc = plt.scatter(df['A'], 
                 df['B'], 
                 s=0, 
                 c=c1, 
                 cmap='jet', # Use the same Cmap
                 vmin = vmin,
                 vmax = vmax,
                 facecolors='none')
plt.grid()
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc)
cbar.set_label('C', rotation=270, labelpad=20)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `vmin` and `vmax` params in `plt.scatter()`.

```
sc = plt.scatter(df['A'], 
                 df['B'], 
                 s=0, 
                 c=c1, 
                 cmap='jet',
                 vmin = 0,
                 vmax = 4,
                 facecolors='none')
```

[image]

If you want to ajust the color of the circles based on the color-map, then you need to use `Normalize(vmin, vmax) and pass the color-map to the circle plot with the normalized value.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas            as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm
from sklearn import preprocessing
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,4], 
                   'B':[3,1,5,1,2,4,5,2,3], 
                   'C':[4,2,4,1,3,3,4,2,1]})

# set the Colour
x              = df.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled       = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df_S           = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
c1             = df['C']
c2             = df_S[2]
cmap = cm.jet
vmin = 0
vmax = 5 #your max Y is 5, not 4
norm = Normalize(vmin, vmax)

# Graph
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B']):
    circle = plt.Circle((a, 
                         b), 
                         1, # Size
                         color=cmap(norm(b)), 
                         lw=5, 
                         fill=False)
    ax.add_artist(circle)

plt.xlim([0,5])
plt.ylim([0,5])
plt.xlabel('A')
plt.ylabel('B')
ax.set_aspect(1.0)

sc = plt.scatter(df['A'], 
                 df['B'], 
                 s=0, 
                 c=c1, 
                 cmap='jet',
                 vmin = vmin,
                 vmax = vmax,
                 facecolors='none')
plt.grid()

cbar = plt.colorbar(sc)
cbar.set_label('C', rotation=270, labelpad=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This has changed the minimum value of the colour bar which is exactly what I asked for. It has however not changed the colour of the circles. The colour of the circles must therefore be out of whack with the colour bar. I suppose I need to some how do the same thing on both graphs.

Comment: Yes, that is another question. I have added a solution in the answer.

Comment: I don't know why but it is now using B to set the colour of the circles, not C!

Comment: `color=cmap(norm(b))` it sets the color based on your `b` variable, you can set whatever variable you want. I have assumed you wanted to use `b` that is the Y ax value of the center of your circles.

Answer (score 0):

You could fiddle with the [extend parameters](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) to get this output:

```
fraction = 1/3 # colorbar axis min is 1, max is 4, steps are 0.5 
               # => 2*(1/6) to get to 0
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, extend="min", extendfrac=fraction, extendrect=True)
```

[image]

But the extension will be unlabelled.